# How can we remove comments from apple documentation code

Tags: ios, xcode

Do we have any shortcut to remove iOS documentation commnets?
When we copy the code from apple documentation it's copied along with **///**.
I would like to uncomment with the Xcode shortcut (if any).

```swift
///
///     struct PlayButton: View {
///         @Binding var isPlaying: Bool
///
///         var body: some View {
///             Button(action: {
///                 self.isPlaying.toggle()
///             }) {
///                 Image(systemName: isPlaying ? "pause.circle" : "play.circle")
///             }
///         }
///     }
///
```

Comment: ⌘/ removes only two slashes. A workaround is: Press ⌘F, type ///, select `Replace`, click `All`

Comment: Yeah, I do know this, but searching something cmd+/

Comment: Another way is to write a Source Editor Extension and assign a custom shortcut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach would be to edit multiple lines simultaneously and remove them.

1. Hold `⌥ Option`
2. Drag your cursor from the first line (behind the 3rd slash) to the last line (so in a straight line down)
3. You're now editing multiple lines. Press `delete` 3 times to remove the slashes, then `escape` to exit this mode.

So in short: *`⌥ Option` + drag down* on the lines you want to edit.

Comment: No problem! I use this feature all the time, it can come in handy in many situations!

Answer (score 0):

You can select your code and use **Command + /**